# TYPO3 8.7.x hide some tt_content fields

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Was solution for tt_content overrides here http://p.cweiske.de/243, looks like

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['date']['displayCond'] = 'FIELD:CType:!=:fluidcontent_content';
```

which hides date or other fields from tt_content in backend. In TYPO3 8.7.x this approach doesn't work anymore. I checked displayCond still exist https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond.

Seems to be a problem in `Overrides`. In my case it was just file `myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`.

Looks like system does not load this any more. Could somebody help?

Comment: is your extension activated?

Comment: yes i also tried add to other active extention

Comment: Did you clear the system cache?

Comment: Sure, i event used 'rm -rf typo3temp/*'

Comment: Hi, you can use the Configuration Module (System) in the Backend to check if and how your overrides come into effect.